# Why can ASP.net code in VBScript tags run at page load despite being in no sub or method?

Tags: asp.net

I don't use Visual Studio to write ASP.net websites.

If I put ASP.net code in VBScript tags `<%` at the top of my `.aspx` document, it runs without needing to be in a sub `page_load`.

In fact, I am including another `.aspx` file that does contain a `page_load` sub that runs on every page of this small project.

Why don't I get errors like

> Statement cannot appear outside of a method body

with this implementation?

Comment: Are you using VBScript in classic ASP or VB.Net in ASP.Net?  There are differences between these two.

Comment: JB King: i have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tags, called **Code Render Blocks**, are there by design and covered in the documentation here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=VS.71).aspx

I have yet to find a reason that Microsoft included them, other than that it's an easy way to put server-side variables or method output into the page.  I believe that it's a holdover from classic ASP.

Based on the behavior, the reason they don't throw an error is because they are evaluated during the Page_Render phase (putting the ececution within a method body).  You can see this by stepping through your code in Visual Studio.

Personally, however, I prefer to use Labels or other controls, and set the text in the code-behind. There are a few exceptions where I've used this syntax for one reason, and one reason only: So that I could change the code without having to recompile the web app.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is allowed for data binding and for compatibility with classic asp.

Answer (score 0):

They are called [Embedded Code Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28VS.80%29.aspx) and they are executed during Page's Render event according to [this post](http://michielvoo.net/blog/expressions-vs-statements-part-2-asp-net-code-block-types/).